# Is there an error in this Precalculus handout on Law of Cosins and Herons Formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, factoring, area

Apologies, I can't include images - not enough rep.

An example exercise dealing with the Law of Cosines to prove Heron's formula for the area of a triangle has me befuddled.

After substitution using the Law of Cosines into a formula for area involving cosine :

$$ A^2 = \frac{1}{4} a^2b^2 \frac {(a+b+c)(a+b-c)}{2ab}\frac {(c+a-b)(c-a+b)}{2ab} $$

The handout simplifies this directly to:

$$ A^2 = \frac{(a+b+c)}{2} \frac{(a+b-c)}{2}  \frac {(c+a-b)}{2}\frac {(c-a+b)}{2} $$

I see  how the $a^2b^2$ with the two factors of $ab$. Then, I see how the 2 rationals on the right are factored into four.

**But what happened to the factor of $\frac14$??**

---

Direct-Link to the image of the above problem cut from professor's precalculus handout:
http://s13.postimg.org/5os0orttj/Precalc_Lawof_Cosines_NYU_PDF3.png

Original source -- Problem On page 3 of this pdf:

http://cims.nyu.edu/~kiryl/Precalculus/Section_6.6-The%20Law%20of%20Cosines/The%20Law%20of%20Cosines.pdf

Comment: Both expressions have four factors of $2$ in the denominator: in the first one they’re split amongst the $4$ of the $\frac14$ and the two $2$s in the $2ab$ denominators, and in the second one there’s one in each factor.

Comment: It became $\frac12 \times \frac12$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ahmed Hussein noticed, it gets split up between the $2$'s in the denominators:

$$\frac14=\frac12\cdot\frac12$$

This accounts for all of the $2$'s in the denominators.

Comment: Thank you -- and you too, Brian and Ahmed. Now I see where my mistake in the mental math took place: incorrectly at the problem as if it had six factors of 2. Very simple mistake, humbling. Thanks again everyone. @Brian-M-Scott